# Программно узнать свой ip адрес в Rust на Windows

Tags: windows, сеть, rust

Какие есть библиотеки? Я нашёл https://github.com/ivanceras/machine-ip, но это только для `unix`, а нужно для `windows`

Comment: решено https://docs.rs/ipconfig/0.1.5/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/ipconfig/

Answer (score 1):

C rust не знаком ни разу, но полагаю, что нужно дёргать winapi

GetAdaptersAddresses из https://docs.rs/crate/pnet/0.1.1/source/src/bindings/winpcap.rs вроде как раз это и делает